# File Name Change in Python: loop over dictionary values

Tags: python, rename

In a folder, I have a file called "*şğçı*" and want to change it to "*sgci*". I created two lists and combined them to create a dictionary. Using the os library, I want to loop over this dictionary to replace the Turkish characters in the file names with the English character alternatives.

```
import os

path = r"C:\Users\ALpeR\Desktop/test_files"

turkish_character = ["ğ", "ç", "ş", "ü", "ö", "ı"]

english_alternatives = ["g", "c", "s", "u", "o", "i"]

character_dictionary = dict(zip(turkish_character, english_alternatives))
    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file = file.lower()
        for key, value in character_dictionary.values():
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, file.replace(f"{key}",f"{value}")))
```

I believe that the problem could be in the last two lines of my code.

Comment: "I believe that the problem is at the two lines of my code." What two lines

Comment: Last two lines of my code. The problem is probably related to my wrong doing loop in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original filename needs to be saved for [**`os.rename`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) before the dict mapping.

Replace your for loop by this :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        new_file = file
        new_file = new_file.lower()
        for key, value in character_dictionary.items():
            new_file = new_file.replace(key, value)
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, new_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

For each key-value pair when you iterate over the dictionary, you're changing the file. However, when you return to the loop for the next iteration, your first argument of os.rename is the original file name. You change "şğçı" to "sğçı" on the first iteration, "şgçı" on the second, and so on.

You should be able to fix this by adding the last line to your existing loop:

```
for key, value in character_dictionary.values():
    os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, file.replace(f"{key}",f"{value}")))
    file = file.replace(f{key}", f"{value}")
```